# Hide submenu wordpress?

Tags: hacks

How to hide customize menu and another submenu on wordpress?

I already hide some submenu on wordpress like

```
function hiden() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );//widget
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' ); //editor
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme_options' );} //theme-option
add_action('admin_head', 'hiden');
```

but if I want to remove customize menu `remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'customize.php' )`... but It can't... Anybody can help me, whats wrong ???
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deal with wp menus you shoudl use admin_menu filter.

```
add_filter('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_filter',500);
function admin_menu_filter(){
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );//widget
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php'); //editor
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme_options' ); //theme-option
}
add_action('admin_print_styles-themes.php', 'hide_customize');
function hide_customize(){
    echo '<style>#customize-current-theme-link{display:none;}</style>';
}
```

you can place it to your plugin or functions.php in your theme.

Comment: its same can not work for hide customize... 

function admin_menu_filter(){
 remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'customize.php');
}
add_filter('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_filter',500);

Comment: if you want just "hide" but not to remove page, you can use a updated sample.

Comment: great idea @code monkey. Thanks so much... But anyway, I wanna be know... how to disable customize option because if just hiden, user can fill customize.php in url ???

Comment: if you will remove capability 'edit_theme_options' of user roles of your user wouldn't be able to user customization url. but even edit theme options...

Answer (score -1):

The correct page url of customize.php is `customize.php?return=%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-admin%2Fnav-menus.php`

So to remove the submenu use:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'customize.php?return=%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-admin%2Fnav-menus.php' ); // hide the customize submenu
```